# how to use if statements to read from two columns in Python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a file called `students.csv`. There are a couple of columns. I want to use `if` statements for two columns, the `gender` and the `scores`. I want to display the male students who have got the highest scores (in descending order). So, I need to write a script that can read from the csv file and combine these two columns (gender and scores).

I tried to use:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('students.csv')

print(data[data["Gender"] == 1])
```

Here I gave male students = 1, and female = 0.
But, I don't know how to print the male students who have got the highest scores.

Comment: You need to sort the filtered df or just get the max of that column `data.loc[data['Gener']==1, 'Scores'].max()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting `Gender` and  [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), with parameter `n`, if you need more as one values:

> **n** : int
>
> Return this many descending sorted values

```
print data
   Scores  Gender
0      10       0
1       5       1
2       5       0
3       7       1
4       8       1
5       3       0

print data.loc[data['Gender']==1, 'Scores'].nlargest(n=3)
4    8
3    7
1    5
Name: Scores, dtype: int64
```

If you need only the highest score, use [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html), as mentioned `Edchum` in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032599/how-to-use-if-statements-to-read-from-two-columns-in-python/36032929#comment59714701_36032599):

```
print data.loc[data['Gender']==1, 'Scores'].max()
8
```

Or use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Gender` with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) for all `Gender`:

```
print data.groupby('Gender')['Scores'].nlargest(n=2)
Gender   
0       0    10
        2     5
1       4     8
        3     7
dtype: int64
```

If you need names, you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by both `indexes`:

```
print data
  Names  Scores  Gender
0     a      10       0
1     b       5       1
2     c       5       0
3     d       7       1
4     e       8       1
5     f       3       0

print data.groupby('Gender')['Scores'].nlargest(n=2).reset_index(level=0,name='Max')
   Gender  Max
0       0   10
2       0    5
4       1    8
3       1    7

df =pd.merge(data[['Names']], 
             data.groupby('Gender')['Scores'].nlargest(n=2).reset_index(level=0, name='Max'),
             left_index=True, 
             right_index=True)
               
  Names  Gender  Max
0     a       0   10
2     c       0    5
4     e       1    8
3     d       1    7
```

If you need only one `Gender`, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print data
  Names  Scores  Gender
0     a      10       0
1     b       5       1
2     c       5       0
3     d       7       1
4     e       8       1
5     f       3       0

print data.loc[data['Gender']==1, 'Scores'].nlargest(n=2)
4    8
3    7
Name: Scores, dtype: int64

print pd.concat([data['Names'], 
                 data.loc[data['Gender']==1, 'Scores'].nlargest(n=2)], 
                 axis=1, 
                 join='inner')
                 
  Names  Scores
4     e       8
3     d       7
```

Or simplier solution is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) again:

```
print data
  Names  Scores  Gender
0     a      10       0
1     b       5       1
2     c       5       0
3     d       7       1
4     e       8       1
5     f       3       0

print data.loc[data['Gender'] == 1, 'Scores'].nlargest(n=2).index
Int64Index([4, 3], dtype='int64')

print data.loc[data.loc[data['Gender'] == 1,'Scores'].nlargest(n=2).index,['Names','Scores']]
  Names  Scores
4     e       8
3     d       7
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I think nlargest is more appropriate for my work. Just one more thing, can I add the names of the students together with the results?. I mean, I want to display the names of the students who have the highest scores as well.

Comment: Thanks jezrael - That's great. Since I only need to display the male students, I tried:  df =pd.merge(data[['Names']], 
             data.groupby['Gender']==1  and I completed the script. But I does not give me the male students!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
pandas.DataFrame.sort_values(by='Scores')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .max() command in pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("student.csv")

data = df[df["Gender"]==1].max()

print data
```

Output:

```
stud       daniel
Gender     1
marks     78
dtype: object
```